# Laravel 5.1 - Eloquent Relationships Update Function

Tags: laravel, sql-update, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1.

I have **two** table, `user` table, and `users_detail` table with `oneToOne` relationship.
I already success to show that two data table into one form.

Now I want to run `update` function in my controller. I already know how to run `update` function in **single** table in my other project. Can any of you give me a clue how to run `update` this **two** table in single controller?

Are we need to use this Laravel `update()` function to? or else?

I use this on my `view`:

```
...
{!! Form::model($users, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => 'dashboard.user.update', $users -> id]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('User ID', 'User ID:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('id', $users->id, $attributes = array('id'=>'disabledInput', 'Disabled', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'User ID')); !!}
    </div>
...
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Place Of Birth', 'Place Of Birth:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('placeOfBirth', $users->UsersDetail->placeOfBirth, $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Place Of Birth')); !!}
    </div>
...
...
{!! Form::close() !!}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a nice trick to do that all in one line.  associate() is used to update a belongsTo() relationship.

It will work like this

```
    $user = User::find($id);
    $record= new User_Detail($request->all());

    $record->user()->associate($user);
    $record->save();
```

for many to many relationships you can use attach to sync models

Ill use articles for this example.

```
    $new_article = new Article($request->all());
    $new_article->save(); //I need to save it first so that we the article ID

    Auth::user()->article()->attach($new_artcile->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way. It was not as difficult as I though.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    //          
    $usersUpdate = $request->all(); //get all value from form

    $users = User::find($id); //find the primary key of User table
    $usersDetail = UsersDetail::find($id); //find the foreign key UsersDetail table

    $users->update($usersUpdate); //update the User table
    $usersDetail->update($usersUpdate); //update the UsersDetail table

    return redirect('dashboard/user');
}
```